# Code good for 3 classes: MailItem, AppointmentItem or MeetingItem

Tags: vba, class, outlook, derived-class

I mean to write code that will apply equally to objects `olObj` of class (type) either `MailItem`, `AppointmentItem` or `MeetingItem`. The properties that I would use are those common to all classes (e.g., `Subject`).

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gsmyth/archive/2012/07/01/there-s-more-to-outlook-than-mailitems.aspx), there is no base class for them. Nevertheless, it appears that something can be done about this in C#.

Is there a way to do this in VBA, other than repeating the code for each class?

Comment: In Outlook, `Item Object` have `Class Property`. When I write a code, I always check for that property and then adjust the assigning of variable accordingly (if it is MailItem, TaskItem, MeetingItem etc.). I'm just wondering why you need to create a new Class for that. Or maybe I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @L42 - That is an option possibly useful for any case, with two comments:
1) `olObj.Class` returns an `enum` `OlObjectClass`; its use may be less convenient than `TypeName(olObj)` (or use of `OlItemType`, but I do not know how to retrieve it). For instance, case `TypeName(olObj)` = `MeetingItem` encompasses several cases of `olObj.Class`, and one should test for all of them.
2) I do not see how you would "adjust the assigning of variable accordingly". It would be very interesting if you could post code.
I do not mean to create a new Class.
Thanks

Comment: Dmitry's post is very close to what I'm doing. But what I did is still use Early bind and assign the Item to a variable of its type (depending what class it is as what Dmitry posted). There might be a possibility that we're still on a different page, so might as well provide a scenario or a sample repeated code for each class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use late binding (declare the item as a generic Object) to access common properties such as Subject. Item type specific properties can be accessed by checking the Class property first (exposed by all OOM objects)

```
olMail = 43
olAppointment = 26
olMeetingRequest = 53
olMeetingCancellation = 54  
olMeetingResponseNegative = 55
olMeetingResponsePositive = 56
olMeetingResponseTentative = 57
```

Comment: Could you refine your example? I would like to handle MeetingItem in [QuoteFixMacro](https://github.com/macros4outlook/quotefixmacro). It is unclear to me how to apply that code.

Comment: @koppo - please start a new thread with the relevant snippets of your code included.